# Website is under spam backlink attack

Tags: spam, disavow-links

Our website's ranking has been dramatacically dropped.
We now realized there are too many spam backlinks and obviously someone is attacking to our website.
There are more than 10,000 backlinks from 10-20 domains and hundreds subdomains.

When we navigate to this websites we're seeing this(apologies but that's the only way to show we're under attack and serious.)

[image]

Sample links(subdomains);

aforex-broker.pintarcochequatrecarreres.es

actionforex-audusd.lombardovini.it

actionforex-audusd.tiandemarbella.es

calforex-montreal.lembrat.es

We have submitted the domains with Google Disavow tool but any suggestions would be appreciated.

I think this backlinks will continue to come from other domains.
And not sure how we can recover our rankings loss.